# multiplicative distance between graph nodes

Tags: r, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I want to find the distance between all nodes in a graph, but rather than summing the edge weights I want to multiply them.

As an example:

```
library(igraph)

# create a weighted adjacency matrix
mx <- structure(c(0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))

## convert to igraph object
mx2 <- graph.adjacency(mx, weighted = TRUE)
```

I can get the distance between all nodes as follows:

```
shortest.paths(mx2)

 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0  0.5  1.0  1.0  1.5
[2,]  0.5  0.0  0.5  0.5  1.0
[3,]  1.0  0.5  0.0  1.0  0.5
[4,]  1.0  0.5  1.0  0.0  1.5
[5,]  1.5  1.0  0.5  1.5  0.0
```

But this calculates the distance between all nodes by summing the relevant weights I want to multiply them, which would result in the following:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] 0.000 0.50 0.25 0.250 0.125
[2,] 0.500 0.00 0.50 0.500 0.250
[3,] 0.250 0.50 0.00 0.250 0.500
[4,] 0.250 0.50 0.25 0.000 0.125
[5,] 0.125 0.25 0.50 0.125 0.000
```

As far as I can see this can't be done using "out of the box"  options in igraph, and I am struggling to figure it out on my own (in the real data the matrices are much larger, and a variety of sizes). Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing a function as in the answer above is surely the better way to go. But another way to think about the problem is that if you want products of weights, and `shortest.paths()` gives you sums of weights, then if you feed the `shortest.paths()` function the log of your weights, the exponent of the result will equal the product of weights.

This is a little finickier in practice than I thought it would be, as your weights fall between 0 and 1 and the `shortest.paths()` algorithm will not accept negative weights, but you can work around by multiplying through by -1 before and after computing the weights.

```r
library(igraph)

## Cheat and log it
ln.mx <- structure(c(0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
ln.mx <- ifelse(ln.mx!=0, log(ln.mx), 0) 

## convert to igraph object
ln.mx2 <- graph.adjacency(ln.mx, weighted = TRUE)

# The issue with the approach is that the shortest.path algorithm doesn't like
# negative weights. Since your weights fall in (0,1) their log is negative.
# We multiply edge weights by -1 to swap the sign, and then will 
# multiply again by -1 to get
# the result
E(ln.mx2)$weight <- -1*E(ln.mx2)$weight

# The result is just the regular shortest paths algorithm,
# times -1 (to undo the step above) and exponentiated to undue the logging
res <- exp(shortest.paths(ln.mx2)* -1)

# its still not perfect since the diagonal distance defaults to
# zero and exp(0) is 1, not 0. So we manually reset the diagonal
diag(res) <- 0

# The result is as hoped
res
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
#> [1,] 0.000 0.50 0.25 0.250 0.125
#> [2,] 0.500 0.00 0.50 0.500 0.250
#> [3,] 0.250 0.50 0.00 0.250 0.500
#> [4,] 0.250 0.50 0.25 0.000 0.125
#> [5,] 0.125 0.25 0.50 0.125 0.000
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for this, I will likely use DJack's solution but this will be really helpful in other situations.

Comment: I have been playing around with your solution and have come across an issue, when my matrix contains a mix of 0's, values between 0 and 1, and 1's it does not work, because log(1) == 0, I thought it would be simple to fix but am struggling, can you see a simple solution? Cheers.

Comment: hi @flee, if you look at the toy code in my answer above you can see that its actually the same as the situation you describe: there are a bunch of zero weights. I get around this by only logging the non-zero values -- that's the line above that reads `ifelse(ln.mx!=0, log(ln.mx), 0)`. Since a weight 0 link adds nothing to the distance it doesn't matter if they are treated somewhat inconsistently -- they will not effect the outcome as they are weight zero.

Comment: hi @gfgm, thanks for the quick response! Maybe I am miss understanding but I think the problem still persists. Try replacing a 0.5 with a 1 in your toy example and rerunning the code, the result is not the multiplicative path weight (due to the 1 getting logged when it needs to stay a 1). E.g. if a path has the weights (0.5, 0.5, 1) the result should = 0.5 x 0.5 x 1 = 0.25, but this is not what is produced.

Comment: sorry @flee was off for the weekend. I think logging the 1's should work fine. Consider .5 x .5 x 1 = ln(.5) + ln(.5) + ln(1) = ln(.5) + ln(.5) +0 = .5 x .5 = .5 x .5 x 1. The issue I think is that in the toy example above I logged the weights first and then created the graph object, with the result that the graph is mutilated. Try making the graph first and then setting the weights as `E(ln.mx2)$weight <- -1 * (ifelse(E(ln.mx2)$weight != 0, log(E(ln.mx2)$weight), 0)`.

Comment: No worries at all! That works perfectly, I spent ages fiddling with the order without any luck. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proposal. There is probably a lot of room for improvement, but it gives the expected output. The idea is to extract the shortest path for each pair of nodes and then, multiply the weights associated to each path (I used some code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49697124/2245102)).

```
shortest.paths.multi <- function(mx) {
  output <- mx
  mx2 <- graph.adjacency(mx, weighted = TRUE)
  for (r in 1:nrow(mx)){
    for (c in 1:nrow(mx)){
      SP <- shortest_paths(mx2, from = r, to = c)
      VP <- SP$vpath[[1]]
      EP <- rep(VP, each=2)[-1]
      EP <- EP[-length(EP)]
      output[r, c] <- prod(E(mx2)$weight[get.edge.ids(mx2, EP)])
    }
  }
  diag(output) <- 0
  output
}

shortest.paths.multi(mx)
```

> ```
>       [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
> [1,] 0.000 0.50 0.25 0.250 0.125
> [2,] 0.500 0.00 0.50 0.500 0.250
> [3,] 0.250 0.50 0.00 0.250 0.500
> [4,] 0.250 0.50 0.25 0.000 0.125
> [5,] 0.125 0.25 0.50 0.125 0.000
> ```

**EDIT**

Here is probably a better way to write this function:

```
shortest.paths.multi <- function(r, c){ 
  SP <- shortest_paths(mx2, from = r, to = c)
  VP <- SP$vpath[[1]]
  EP <- rep(VP, each=2)[-1]
  EP <- EP[-length(EP)]
  prod(E(mx2)$weight[get.edge.ids(mx2, EP)])
}

VecFun <- Vectorize(shortest.paths.multi)

output <- outer(1:nrow(mx), 1:ncol(mx), FUN = VecFun)
diag(output) <- 0
output
```