# How to get the sum of edge weight from a node to a node from a graph

Tags: r, graph, igraph

We can sum up the edge weights of the adjacent edges for each vertex using the `strength` function of the `igraph` package. Say we have a graph like the below one

[image: graph]

***Reproducible Data and Code***

```
nodeA <- c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_16", "Node_30")
nodeB <- c("ID_11", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_3", "ID_11", "Node_3")
edge_weight <- c(0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.09, 0.7)
df_1 <- data.frame(nodeA, nodeB, edge_weight)

graph1 <- graph_from_data_frame(df_1, directed = FALSE)
E(graph2)$weight <- df_1$edge_weight
plot(graph1)

edge_strengts <- strength(graph1)
```

The output I am getting from `strength` function is the sum of edge weight from each vertex of the graph.

```
 ID_1    ID_2    ID_3    ID_4    ID_5   ID_16 Node_30   ID_11  Node_3 
   0.50    0.90    2.20    1.50    1.20    0.09    0.70    0.59    0.70
```

Now, I have an edge list and I want to get the sum of the edge weight only for those lists (instead of getting the sum of edges for one vertex). For more clarification, say I have the given edge list,

```
         nodeA      nodeB 
1        ID_2       ID_4  
2        ID_2       ID_5 
3        ID_1       ID_16
```

I want to get the sum of the edges only for the above-listed edge from the given graph (note that the graph is undirected). The output should something like this

```
         nodeA      nodeB    some_of_weight
1        ID_2       ID_4     1.70
2        ID_2       ID_5     1.40
3        ID_1       ID_16    0.59
```

For the first edge (`ID_2 to ID_4`) the sum is `1.70` (e.g: ID_2 to ID_3 = 0.9, and ID_3 to ID_4 = 0.8, so, 0.9 + 0.8 = 1.70) and so on for all edge list.

Can you tell me, how can I do this job?

***Multiple paths for an edge***

The graph can contain multiple paths for edges (i.e., for an edge we can have 1 or more than one different path). Say, we can go `ID_3 to ID_4` in 2 ways (i) ID_3 -- ID_2 -- ID_4 (total path weight is 2.4) and (ii) ID_3 -- ID_5 -- ID_4 (total path weight is 1.5). In this case, I want to take the maximum path weight.

Reproducible data for the multiple paths

```
nodeA <- c("ID_1", "ID_2",  "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_16", "Node_30", "ID_6", "ID_2")
nodeB <- c("ID_11", "ID_3",  "ID_5", "ID_3", "ID_11", "Node_3", "ID_3", "ID_4")
edge_weight <- c(0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.09, 0.7, 1.5)
```

Comment: Your code defines graph1, but also uses graph2.   Should everything be graph1?

Comment: Thank you, this is a typo. Yes, everything is graph1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Since you are looking for longest path between two vertices, you can try the code below

```
df_2$max_sum_weight <- apply(
  df_2,
  1,
  function(x) {
    max(sapply(
      all_simple_paths(graph1, x[["v"]], x[["to"]]),
      function(v) {
        sum(E(graph1)$weight[get.edge.ids(graph1, c(rbind(head(v, -1), v[-1])))])
      }
    ))
  }
)
```

which gives

```
> df_2
     v    to max_sum_weight
1 ID_2  ID_4            2.4
2 ID_2  ID_5            2.3
3 ID_1 ID_16            1.0
4 ID_3  ID_4            2.4
```

Data

```
df_2 <- data.frame(
  v = c("ID_2", "ID_2", "ID_1", "ID_3"),
  to = c("ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_16", "ID_4")
)
```

## Previous Answer (shortest paths)

---

Try `shortest.paths`

```
transform(
  df_2,
  sum_of_weight = diag(shortest.paths(graph1, v, to))
)
```

or

```
transform(
  df_2,
  sum_of_weight = shortest.paths(graph1)[as.matrix(df_2)]
)
```

which gives

```
     v    to sum_of_weight
1 ID_2  ID_4          1.70
2 ID_2  ID_5          1.40
3 ID_1 ID_16          0.59
```

Comment: I am getting `NA` for the 2nd approach and getting an error for the 1st approach (Error in data.frame(list(nodeA = c("ID_3", "ID_2", : arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 4). I assume `df_2` in your code is the edge list, `v` is the from vertex, and `to` is the target vertex. Moreover, I can not use the `shortest_path()`. Because the shortest path is giving the minimum sum for an edge (at the time of multiple paths for an edge) while I want to get the maximum sum for an edge. Would you mind telling me, how can I get the maximum sum (at the time of multiple paths for an edge)

Comment: I have added some reproducible data (in the question) to clarify the multiple paths for an edge, please have a look

Comment: @0Knowledge See my update

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am getting this error `Error in x[["v"]] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: @0Knowledge Did you use `df_2` in my answer? See my update

Comment: If I use your `df_2` the totally fine, but if I use my `df` then I am getting the error. The properties of mt df is `str(mat_pivot_lon_1)
'data.frame': 5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ to: chr  "ID_3" "ID_2" "ID_1" "ID_2" ...
 $ from : chr  "ID_4" "ID_5" "ID_16" "ID_6" ...`

Comment: @0Knowledge change the column names in my df_2 to the names to “to” and “from”, as the sam as in your data frame

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following approach:

Load packages

```r
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union
```

Load data

```r
nodeA <- c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_16", "Node_30")
nodeB <- c("ID_11", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_3", "ID_11", "Node_3")
df <- data.frame(nodeA, nodeB)
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)
E(graph)$weight <- c(0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.09, 0.7)
```

Estimate all pairwise distances between those nodes

```r
all_distances <- distances(
  graph = graph, 
  v = c("ID_2", "ID_2", "ID_1"), 
  to = c("ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_16")
)
```

Check output

```r
all_distances
#>      ID_4 ID_5 ID_16
#> ID_2  1.7  1.4   Inf
#> ID_2  1.7  1.4   Inf
#> ID_1  Inf  Inf  0.59
```

Take the diagonal

```r
diag(all_distances)
#> [1] 1.70 1.40 0.59
```

Please notice that duplicated vertices in the to argument are discarded. For
example:

```r
distances(graph, v = c("ID_2", "ID_5", "ID_4"), c("ID_3", "ID_3", "ID_5"))
#> Error in distances(graph, v = c("ID_2", "ID_5", "ID_4"), c("ID_3", "ID_3", : At structural_properties.c:4461 : Duplicate vertices in `to', this is not allowed, Invalid value
```

In that case, you should compute the “unique” vertices and then take the
relevant matches:

```r
idx_from <- c("ID_2", "ID_5", "ID_4")
idx_to <- c("ID_3", "ID_3", "ID_5") # note the duplicated names
idx_to_unique <- unique(idx_to)
all_distances <- distances(graph, idx_from, idx_to_unique)
diag(all_distances[, match(idx_to, idx_to_unique)])
#> [1] 0.9 0.5 0.7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### EDIT: Add example of summing along longest path

```r
# packages
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(igraph))

# data
nodeA <- c("ID_1", "ID_2",  "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_16", "Node_30", "ID_6", "ID_2")
nodeB <- c("ID_11", "ID_3",  "ID_5", "ID_3", "ID_11", "Node_3", "ID_3", "ID_4")
df <- data.frame(nodeA, nodeB)
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE)
E(graph)$weight <- c(0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.09, 0.7, 1.5)

# Sum weights along longest path
my_sum_weights <- function(graph, from, to) {
  # Compute all simple paths
  my_all_simple_paths <- all_simple_paths(
    graph = graph, 
    from = from, 
    to = to
  )
  
  # Check if there is at least a path
  if (length(my_all_simple_paths) == 0L) {
    return(Inf)
  }
  
  # In that case, sum weights along each path
  all_sum_weights <- numeric(length(my_all_simple_paths))
  for (i in seq_along(my_all_simple_paths)) {
    edges_weights <- E(graph, path = my_all_simple_paths[[i]])$weight
    all_sum_weights[[i]] <- sum(edges_weights)
  }
  
  max(all_sum_weights)
}

# Examples
my_sum_weights(graph, "ID_3", "ID_4")
#> [1] 2.4
my_sum_weights(graph, "ID_6", "ID_4")
#> [1] 3.1
my_sum_weights(graph, "ID_5", "ID_2")
#> [1] 2.3
mapply(my_sum_weights, from = c("ID_3", "ID_6", "ID_1"), MoreArgs = list(to = "ID_4", graph = graph))
#> ID_3 ID_6 ID_1 
#>  2.4  3.1  Inf
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Please notice that *there are exponentially many paths between two vertices of a graph, and you may run out of memory when using all_simple_paths function*.

Comment: thank you very much for your solution. The code is working fine, but, my graph also contains multiple paths for edges. Say, we can go `ID_3` to `ID_4` in 2 ways (I) ID_3 -- ID_2 -- ID_4 (total path weight is 2.4) and (ii) ID_3 -- ID_5 -- ID_4 (total path weight is 1.5). In this case, I want to take the maximum one. But, when I am applying your code, I am getting 1.5. I admit I was unable to clarify my question (and I apologize). Would you mind telling me how can I take the maximum one at the time of multiple paths for en edge?

Comment: I have added some reproducible data (in the question) to clarify the multiple paths for an edge, please have a look.

Comment: See the edited version

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update. When I am applying this function with `idx_from` and `idx_to_unique`, I am getting the output `ID_3 ID_2 ID_1 ID_2 ID_5; 3.2  3.7  1.0  3.7  3.9`, which means the longest path from `ID_3`  is `3.2` (because the function is calculation the longest path in this way for ID_3 -- ID_2 -- ID_4 -- ID_5 = 3.9. But my question was about the longest path weight of a specific vertex to another specific vertex (not the maximum path weight for a vertex to all from the `to vertex list`). As per the question, I should get `2.4` as the longest path for `ID_3` to `ID_4`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. What do you get when you run `my_sum_weights(graph1, "ID_3", "ID_4")`? You don't need the unique idz with the new function (but you need the `mapply` when testing more than 1 node at the same time)

Comment: We have an edge list in the question. Now, say for the last edge (ID_3 to ID_4), I need the longest path weight from ID_3 to ID_4 which is 2.4. But, when I am running your code, it is calculating the longest path for 'ID_3' to all nodes in the 'to' of the `MoreArgs` and giving the output for (any node which has the longest path from the to list for ID_3 node). So, the output I am getting is `3.2` (the path sequence is D_3 -- ID_2 -- ID_4 -- ID_5 = 3.9) and the edge I am getting from this path sequence is ID_3 to ID_5 (which is unwanted and not in the edge list).

Comment: If the function can take only one node as `from` and another node as `to` from the edge list, then, I think, we can get the expected output.